# How to ignore error indicated by clear green triangle?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to clear Excel **"green triangle error"** from entire workbook.

I prepared the below VBA code. It is not clearing the error.

It is consuming more time in each Excel sheet (by clicking the corner of the cell and selecting ignore error).

```
Sub IFERROR()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        On Error Resume Next
        Set frange = ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not frange Is Nothing Then
            For Each c In frange
                If IsError(c.Value) Then
                    If c.Value = CVErr(xlErrDiv0) Then
                        c.Clear
                    End If
                End If
            Next c
        End If
        Set frange = Nothing
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: The little green triangles are determined by the error checking rules you can set in File >Options >Formulas >Error Checking Rules.

Comment: Yes, but to remove that, we need to select the particular cell corner and click the ignore all.

Comment: After you click it away it will return when the sheet is next calculated. However, if you change the rules it won't appear in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn them off **entirely** using:

```
Application.ErrorCheckingOptions.BackgroundChecking = False
```

If you wanted this to only affect one document, you could turn it on/off as the document is activated/deactivated, perhaps storing the previous setting etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

1. **Turn the error checking off**, in the options as @Variatus suggested or with the code @CLR posted. If you use this method you will also turn the error checking off for all the files opened even restarting Excel.
2. **Ignore/Clear the error** as you would do it manually but with code:

   ```
   Dim rCell As Range
   Dim i As Integer

   For Each rCell In Your_Range
       For i = 1 To 9
           rCell.Errors(i).Ignore = True
       Next i
   Next rCell
   ```

   You can reduce the running time by clearing only the type of error you are having and avoiding the loop. Here you are the list of types:

   1. xlEvaluateToError
   2. xlTextDate
   3. xlNumberAsText
   4. xlInconsistentFormula
   5. xlOmittedCells
   6. xlUnlockedFormulaCells
   7. xlEmptyCellReferences
   8. xlListDataValidation
   9. xlInconsistentListFormula

You can either write `Errors(5).Ignore` or `Errors(xlOmittedCells).Ignore` to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

[mikerickson shared an excellent solution](https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/index.php?thread/29089-disable-error-checking-via-vba/&postID=1035971#post1035971) which disables error checking and restores the user's original settings on close:

```
Dim PriorErrorChecking As Boolean

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
 PriorErrorChecking = Application.ErrorCheckingOptions.BackgroundChecking
 Application.ErrorCheckingOptions.BackgroundChecking = False 
End Sub 

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean) 
 Application.ErrorCheckingOptions.BackgroundChecking = PriorErrorChecking
End Sub
```